# Getting Load error in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i am getting the following error when making one form using Rails3.

Error:

```
LoadError in SdfsController#edit

Expected C:/Site/swargadwar_admin/app/models/t_sdf.rb to define T_sdf
Rails.root: C:/Site/swargadwar_admin

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/sdfs_controller.rb:6:in `edit'
```

2nd Error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SdfsController#create

Mysql::Error: Out of range value for column 'Donation_Amount' at row 1: INSERT INTO `t_sdfs` (`Brahmin`, `Created_By`, `Date_Of_Death`, `Deceased_Address1`, `Deceased_Address2`, `Deceased_Block`, `Deceased_Country`, `Deceased_Dist`, `Deceased_Name`, `Deceased_PS`, `Deceased_State`, `Deceased_Village`, `Donation_Amount`, `Donation_Date`, `Doner_Address1`, `Doner_Address2`, `Doner_Block`, `Doner_Country`, `Doner_Dist`, `Doner_MobileNo`, `Doner_Name`, `Doner_PS`, `Doner_Photo`, `Doner_Relationship_ID`, `Doner_Relationship_Other`, `Doner_State`, `Doner_Thumb`, `Doner_Video`, `Doner_Village`, `HCSY_Status`, `Photo`, `Updated_By`, `created_at`, `receipt_no`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Rails.root: C:/Site/swargadwar_admin

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/sdfs_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

I am explaining my code below ,Please check these and let me to know how it will be resolved.

## model/t_sdf.rb

```
  class TSdf < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :Brahmin, :Created_By, :Date_Of_Death, :Deceased_Address1, :Deceased_Address2, :Deceased_Block, :Deceased_Country, :Deceased_Dist, :Deceased_Name, :Deceased_PS, :Deceased_State, :Deceased_Village, :Donation_Amount, :Donation_Date, :Doner_Address1, :Doner_Address2, :Doner_Block, :Doner_Country, :Doner_Dist, :Doner_MobileNo, :Doner_Name, :Doner_PS, :Doner_Photo, :Doner_Relationship_ID, :Doner_Relationship_Other, :Doner_State, :Doner_Thumb, :Doner_Video, :Doner_Village, :HCSY_Status, :Photo, :Updated_By, :receipt_no
   mount_uploader :Photo, PhotoUploader
   mount_uploader :Doner_Photo, DonerPhotoUploader
    end
```

## controller/sdfs_controller.rb

```
class SdfsController < ApplicationController
    def new

    end
    def edit
        @sdf=T_sdf.new
    end
    def create
        @sdf=T_sdf.new(params[:sdf])
        if @sdf.save
            flash[:notice]="Data saved successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'new', :controller => "admins"
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not saved"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
end
```

## views/sdfs/edit.html.erb

```
<center>
    <%= form_for :sdf,:url => {:action => "create" } do |f| %>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Deceased Name</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Deceased_Name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Deceased Address-1</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Deceased_Address1 %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for "name">Deceased Address-2</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Deceased_Address2 %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Deceased Village</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Deceased_Village %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Deceased Block</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Deceased_Block %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Deceased Dist</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Deceased_Dist %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Deceased State</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Deceased_State %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Deceased country</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Deceased_Country %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Deceased PS</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Deceased_PS %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Date of Death</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Date_Of_Death,:id => "popupDatepicker" %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Doner Name</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_Name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Doner mobile no</label>
        <%= f.telephone_field :Doner_MobileNo %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Doner relationship id</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_Relationship_ID %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Other relation ship id</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_Relationship_Other %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Doner Address-1</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_Address1 %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Doner Address-2</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_Address2 %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Doner Village</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_Village %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Doner Block</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_Block %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Doner Dist</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_Dist %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Doner State</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_State %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Doner Country</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_Country %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Doner PS</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Doner_PS %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Donation Amount</label>
        <%= f.text_field :Donation_Amount %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Donation date</label>
        <%= f.date_field :Donation_Date %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Photo</label>
        <%= f.file_field :Photo %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Doner photo</label>
        <%= f.date_field :Doner_Photo %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="name">Bramhin</label>
        <%= f.date_field :Brahmin %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Created</label>
        <%= f.number_field :Created_By %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Updated</label>
        <%= f.number_field :Updated_By %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">HCSY Status</label>
         Yes:<%= f.radio_button :HCSY_Status,'Yes',:checked => true %>
         No: <%= f.radio_button :HCSY_Status,'No' %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
</center>
```

## migrate/20150407215437_create_t_sdfs.rb

```
class CreateTSdfs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :t_sdfs do |t|
      t.string :receipt_no
      t.string :Deceased_Name
      t.string :Deceased_Address1
      t.string :Deceased_Address2
      t.string :Deceased_Village
      t.string :Deceased_Block
      t.string :Deceased_Dist
      t.string :Deceased_State
      t.string :Deceased_Country
      t.string :Deceased_PS
      t.date :Date_Of_Death
      t.string :Doner_Name
      t.string :Doner_MobileNo
      t.integer :Doner_Relationship_ID
      t.string :Doner_Relationship_Other
      t.string :Doner_Address1
      t.string :Doner_Address2
      t.string :Doner_Village
      t.string :Doner_Block
      t.string :Doner_Dist
      t.string :Doner_State
      t.string :Doner_Country
      t.string :Doner_PS
      t.decimal :Donation_Amount, :precision => 3, :scale => 0
      t.datetime :Donation_Date
      t.string :Photo
      t.string :Doner_Photo
      t.string :Doner_Thumb
      t.string :Doner_Video
      t.string :Brahmin
      t.boolean :HCSY_Status
      t.integer :Created_By
      t.integer :Updated_By

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Controller, Change that class name `T_sdf` to `TSdf`.

```
def edit
  @sdf=TSdf.new
end
```

Comment: Hi adoben Can you please help me to resolve a small error which explained below.This error is coming after submitting the form.

Error:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SdfsController#create
app/controllers/sdfs_controller.rb:10:in `create'
Please check my updated model file and try to help me.Thanks

Comment: sure @rajat_474, can you give me the following resultes, params and TSdf.column_names

Comment: Hi,adoben, by help of you i became able to solve my first error.My all above codes are same but i am editing second error again.i am also using carrierwave gem for picture uploading  but i am clicking on submit button this type of error is coming.Please check my updated error above.

Comment: I think your are sending wrong params to `TSdf.new(params[:sdf])`, and ActiveRecord creates wrong create statement. So, i think change all attributes like this `Created_By` to `created_by`. This may help you. or else give me create request `params` and TSdf.column_names  results.

Comment: I updated the migration file above please check this .

Comment: As what i understand from error that maybe `Donation_Amount` value is wrong. and yes you have settled `scale` to 0 so, it will not take 1.1, 1.11 kind of value. check it out that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74637/discussion-between-adoben-and-rajat-474).